# How to Avoid "Unsupported file format" error while reading excel files using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I tried to read .xls file using pandas

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Pavan K\Downloads\StatisticsLiveData.xls")
```

i got an error like:

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml'
```

How to solve this issue. Please help

Comment: try `pd.read_csv('path')` make sure that your file is closed. Or open this file in excel and save as new excel file again

Comment: Hi @sygneto it didnt work.

Comment: i see that you are saving it with old excel format, try to save it in `xlsx` not `xls` . If you have more than one sheet in file , you should use `sheet_name='SheetNo'`

Comment: Try to save it as .csv with excel and then read it as csv in python

Answer (score 0):

If excel opens this file well, try to update your **[xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) version**.